# Excel formula to create year range between two dates (powerquery)

Tags: excel, list, date, powerquery

I want to create a list of the years between two dates in powerquery. I found the below formula but couldnt convert it to PowerQuery.

```
Calculated Table =
GENERATE (
Table1,
VAR Beg =
    YEAR ( Table1[Enrollment Date] )
VAR Fin =
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( YEAR ( Table1[Exit Date] ) ),
        YEAR ( TODAY () ),
        YEAR ( Table1[Exit Date] )
    )
RETURN
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( GENERATESERIES ( Beg, Fin ), "Service Year", [Value] )
)
```

Edited : Solved

Answer (score 0):

then i solved it by a clue from below formula which lists the dates between two days.

```
= Table.FromColumns({List.Transform({Number.From(List.Min(Table1[DUE_DATE]))..Number.From(List.Max(Table1[DUE_DATE]))},Date.From)},type table[Date = date])
```

Here is my solution :

```
let
Source= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tarihler"]}[Content],
first = Number.From(Date.Year(Source {0} [İlk Tarih] )),
last = Number.From(Date.Year(Source {0} [Son Tarih] )),
ListYears =  List.Numbers(first,last-first+1)

in
ListYears
```

I am leaving it here for future searches...

Thanks for reading...